# es6 propertyIsEnumerable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Public methods created through es6 class syntax are not enumerable. What is the difference between 'getname' method written in es5 & es6?

```
function Cat(){
 this.name="cat"
}
Cat.prototype.getname = function() {return this.name}
var cat = new Cat()

class Dog { 
 constructor(){
   this.name="dog"
 } 
 getname() {
   return this.name
 } 
}
var dog = new Dog()

cat.__proto__.propertyIsEnumerable("getname") //true
dog.__proto__.propertyIsEnumerable("getname") //false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a property directly to an object with `obj.property = foo` will always create an enumerable property.

The ES2015 class syntax doesn't do that.

To (partially) replicate the ES2015 functionality in ES5 you'd have to add the `getname` method using `Object.defineProperty(Cat.prototype, 'getname', ...)`

Comment: Is there a reason why the behaviour is different in ES2015. If class syntax is just syntactic sugar, shouldn't methods chained in __proto__ be enumerable?

Comment: It's syntax sugar for defining a prototype chain, but you could have made them non-enumerable in ES5 if you wanted to too if you used `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Sorry, that was meant as a reply for Viswesh, not criticism of the answer.

Comment: @Alnitak Is there any way you can enumerate public methods within class syntax?

Comment: @Viswesh you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Dog.prototype)` to get an array of all properties (enumerable or otherwise) but you'd then have to examine each property to determine if it's a value property or a method.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, ES6 class methods are not enumerable. Another difference is that they are not constructible:

```
new cat.__proto__.getname; // works
new dog.__proto__.getname; // throws a TypeError
```

Also, method code in a class is always [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) code and can take advantage of certain language features like the [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) keyword.

Comment: Also good to clarify that the `super` and `new` restrictions apply to object methods too :)